# blending composites..some explanation please

Tags: java, graphics, blending

I am trying to figure out what Romain Guy did in his blend composite [BlendingComposite--Romain Guy](http://www.curious-creature.org/2006/09/20/new-blendings-modes-for-java2d/). This is what I know at least I think.

1. Image holds its information in an array of colors (info for each pixel)
2. Blending takes those pixels and combines them using algorithm to create a final pixel.

I am confused how to get the pixels arrays of those images and then work with them?

How is the blending composite then created?

Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.aiim.org/documents/standards/pdf/blend_modes.pdf) is the specification describing how to implement the PDF blend modes, which is what are described on the linked page.

Comment: What class to do I extend or implement to make this in android?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android, but you'd probably want to add it to an image class.

Comment: In java, you extend the Composite class but I have no clue what to do for android...lol